# New version doesn't show up

Tags: updates

I have problem updating my current WordPress version (4.7.2) to the latest (4.7.5).

I have multi-site inside "Network admin dashboard". There is no new version

[image: Here is an screenshot.]

What can the problem be?

Thanks!